# Производители пропали в панели администратора OpenCart

Tags: opencart

Создаю производителя он создается, но в админке

1. он не отображается в списке производителей (хотя счетчик производителей плюсуется)
2. нельзя выбрать при добавлении товара, соответственно товар без него

Бывало что портачил, и просто удалял и заливал заново на сервак все файлы, не это ли причина? (со всем остальным таких приколов нет)

Comment: Делайте нормальный деплой, повторите проблему локально и исправьте. По какой причине не выводятся данные никто кроме вас узнать не может.

Comment: а вы решили вопрос со списком производителей ? у меня такая же проблема